# Run gwt app with jetty

Tags: maven, gwt, jetty

I want to run a gwt app with jetty - that is with `jetty:run`

The problem I'm finding is that jetty is not picking up the gwt compiled artifacts.

I run gwt:compile and it creates my module in the target// location.

Jetty does not seem to include that folder in the web app though.

I know this as when I start the app it does not find the `<module>/<module>.nocache.js` content.

Answer (score 2):

Use `jetty:run-exploded` instead; or configure Jetty to look at your `target/<finalName>` for web resources [in addition to](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#using-multiple-webapp-root-directories) or [instead of](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#configuring-your-webapp) `src/main/webapp`.